# ie10 and 11 fail to update visible binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following visible binding in ko:

```
<div data-bind="visible: !hasConnection()" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        You have no connections created yet!
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: getAvailableConnections">Create one now?</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

the respective sections of the VM for this binding are:

```
existingConnectionsListViewModel.connections = mapping.fromJS([]);
existingConnectionsListViewModel.hasConnection = ko.computed(function () {
    return existingConnectionsListViewModel.connections().length > 0;
});
```

when the connections array changes the visible bindings (there are more visible bindings like this on my view) work in all browsers including ie8 and 9

**Issue:**

**In ie 10 and 11 observableArray created using mapping.fromJS([]) does not get updated if the console window is closed**

---

Further investigation:

If while the console window is closed I create a connections making existingConnectionsListViewModel.connections().length to be 1

I can see afterwards that the array has not been updated:

[image]

If I refresh the page or go through the whole process with dev toolbar open then the array will have the correct number of items.

- I Have no `console.log` statements in my code.
- Wrapping the visible binding in single quotes makes no difference to the issue
- the whole module is in strict mode
- doctype is: XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Comment: does it fail only on IE 10 and 11?

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear. edited the question

Comment: try this <div data-bind="visible: !hasConnection" >

Comment: updated the question. As there are more visible bindings in my code. only this one is accessed like a function. No that wouldn't make a difference. However still did try and still makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having issues regarding part of the code not working when console window is closed there are is also another important thing you should check except not having console.log statement in your code.

And that is ajax caching. IE is notorious for caching ajax results and if your response is cached then your observable is not going to receive the new data to notify your visible bindings.

Make sure you have `cache: false` enabled as a global setting for whichever ajax tool you are using.

for jQ or amplify use:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```